# Module Python on Mac

Tags: python

I'm currently starting to learn python with no previous coding experience. I'm trying to learn "Module" (that's what it's named in German, don't know if it's the same in Englisch), the "import" thing and wanted to ask if somebody could tell me, how it works on MacOS. Unfortunately my tutorial is for Windows and I googled this problem but it seems like Google won't help me either.
Till now I tried: import Skript (the name of my Skript)

But my Terminal gives me: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Skript'

What have I done wrong?
I know, pathing is different on Mac but how does it work?
I hope someone can help me.
Yours Oskar

Comment: there is no difference in how packages work between windows and mac ... most likely you are not running in the same folder where Skript.py is located ... and maybe need to add it to the PYTHONPATH

Comment: @JoranBeasley it's definitely running in the same folder.                                         File "/Users/oskarmeier/Skript.py", line 1, in <module>
    import somemodule
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'somemodule' Thats everything I get.

Comment: @JoranBeasley Nevermind, I got my problem!! Thanks for helping me.

Comment: run `os.getcwd()` that will tell you the directory you are running in ... then you can use `os.listdir(".")` to see any files in that folder